# Bootstrap, stretching last column

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have this layout made with bootstrap each witdth is 4 units
[image: Current]
This is what im trying to achive
[image: Wanted]

Basically I want last elements to stretch to fill.
If there were only four elements last one should be full width.

### My attempt

I tried to add `flex-fill` and `flex-grow-1` to each column but it doesn't seem to change anything.

**Can I achive this effect whithout js?**

### Code

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-around row">
        <div class="my-2 col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title">One</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="my-2 col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title">Two</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="my-2 col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title">Three</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="my-2 col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title">Four</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="my-2 col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title">Five</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the default columns to have width 4, like `col-md-4`, I can suggest the following approach:

Do not specify column width in the HTML and justify the content evenly:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly row">
    <div class="my-2 col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">One</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-2 col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">Two</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-2 col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">Three</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-2 col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">Four</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-2 col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">Five</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then set the minimum size of all columns:

```
.my-2 {
 flex-basis: 33.3%;
 min-width: 33.3%;
}
```

Comment: Simple and without creating another row. Exaclty what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap comes up with a lot of different solutions to achieve multiple views. What you've been trying so far was almost correct. However, your last `col` ist currently just looking a bit wrong. You might exchange your last `col`s classes by the following.

`<div class="my-2 col flex-grow">`

This does simply 2 things.

1. Using `col` you're letting flexbox decide how much space to take
2. Adding `flex-grow` you're telling flexbox to use and fill up `any left space`

Answer (score 0):

Use [equal-width](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#equal-width) utility of bootstrap. Divide the area in 2 rows with same width (col-md-8 here) and then place as many divs of equal width.

**Sample below:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-around row">

       <!-- row-1 -->
       <div class="row col-md-8">
   <div class="my-2 col">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title">One</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="my-2 col">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title">Two</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="my-2 col">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title">Three</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- row-2 -->
    <div class="row col-md-8">
    
  <div class="my-2 col">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title">Four</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="my-2 col">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-title">Five</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
   
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create using [**'Equal-width'**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width), for more details go through the Bootstrap 4 Grid System.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width